# Mount command cannot use xargs

Tags: bash

I made this command.

```
  aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag-value,Values=jenkins" |  jq '.Reservations[0].Instances[0].PrivateIpAddress' | mount -t nfs -o vers=4,nfsvers=4 xargs:/mnt/gradle /mnt/gradle
```

But seems like the xargs cannot be used in the mount command. 
This is the error

mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server xargs: Name or service not known

Any idea what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like:

```
.... | xargs -I'{}' mount -t nfs -o vers=4,nfsvers=4 <IP_or_hostname>:'{}' '{}'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what you're trying to do.
But first let's make that line readable by breaking lines:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag-value,Values=jenkins" | \
  jq '.Reservations[0].Instances[0].PrivateIpAddress' | \
  mount -t nfs -o vers=4,nfsvers=4 xargs:/mnt/gradle /mnt/gradle
```

You are trying to pipe to the `mount` command.
That cannot work, because the `mount` command doesn't take parameters from `stdin`. To run `mount` for each line of `stdin`, you can use `xargs`:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag-value,Values=jenkins" | \
  jq '.Reservations[0].Instances[0].PrivateIpAddress' | \
  xargs -I{} mount -t nfs -o vers=4,nfsvers=4 '{}':/mnt/gradle /mnt/gradle
```

I assume that the lines in `stdin` are ip addresses. For example if it contains the line `192.168.1.10`, then the following command will get executed:

```
mount -t nfs -o vers=4,nfsvers=4 192.168.1.10:/mnt/gradle /mnt/gradle
```

However, if there are multiple lines in the input, I'm not sure what you expect to happen. With this example I gave, only the last server will be accessible via the local mount point `/mnt/gradle`.